# android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing" equivalent in livecode

Tags: android, ios, livecode

Do you know the equivalent of eclipse code `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"` in livecode? This prevents changing the layout when the keyboard shows up.

Note: I created a web apps (html5 packed as android and ios apps)

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried it already? When I do this, nothing changes by default. If you wanted the lay-out to change, you'd have to write a script for that.

Answer (score -1):

The default behavior is not to change the layout, so you don't need to script it.

Comment: You're plain wrong. The default behavior is unspecified. A quote from the docs: `It is unspecified whether the activity's main window resizes to make room for the soft keyboard, or whether the contents of the window pan to make the current focus visible on-screen. [...] *This is the default* setting for the behavior of the main window.`

Comment: No. This is a discussion of the LiveCode scripting language using the LiveCode development environment, and the docs you mention aren't from Livecode. When developing in the LiveCode IDE, layouts are not altered unless you specifically script it. It would be nice if you'd remove the negative vote, since you're wrong.

Comment: That's not possible. :((( At least until the answer is edited. So says the SO bubble.